What is the opposite of logical positivism?
Is it logical negativism or something else?
Whatever the core assertions of logical positivism are, what school of thought resembles the negation of those assertions? What stance is incompatible with logical positivism?

A slightly more serious answer would be Look at Platonism, Existentialism, Phenomenology, Mysticism. In particular Platonism is always a good start. Just as everyone should brush their teeth, sll philosophy beginners should start Platonism. (And others)

Illogical negativism...but see Heidegger.

You forgot to apply de Morgan @MauroALLEGRANZA

Maybe useful: Carnap versus Heidegger as well as Simon Critchley, A Case Study in Misunderstanding: Heidegger and Carnap.

Anti-scientism
